# Проблема со словами в шапке в bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, css-animation

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал использовать разные способы. Даже если и было всё в ряд present past can ,но will улетает вниз. Помогите поставить все слова в ряд. Это с анимацией.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.topmenu>li {
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.topmenu>li>a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px;
}

.topmenu li a:hover {
  color: #D5B45B;
}

.submenu {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #273037;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.submenu a {
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.submenu li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.topmenu>li:hover .submenu {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

#carousel {
  padding: 0px;
}

#bd {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

@media (min-width: 1351px) {
  #description1 {
    width: 69%;
    border: 3px dashed grey;
    padding: 4%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 17%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
  }
  #onthispage {
    font-size: 3.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
  }
  #text1 {
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #text2 {
    width: 103%;
    height: 3%;
    font-size: 2.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1350px) and (min-width: 1061px) {
  #description1 {
    width: 60%;
    border: 3px dashed grey;
    padding: 4%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 18%;
    margin-bottom: 2%
  }
  #onthispage {
    font-size: 2.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
  }
  #text1 {
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #text2 {
    width: 103%;
    height: 3%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1060px) and (min-width: 821px) {
  #description1 {
    width: 60%;
    border: 3px dashed grey;
    padding: 4%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 18%;
    margin-bottom: 2%
  }
  #onthispage {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
  }
  #text1 {
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #text2 {
    width: 103%;
    height: 3%;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 820px) and (min-width: 720px) {
  #description1 {
    width: 70%;
    border: 3px dashed grey;
    padding: 4%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 2%
  }
  #onthispage {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
  }
  #text1 {
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #text2 {
    width: 103%;
    height: 3%;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 719px) and (min-width: 550px) {
  #description1 {
    width: 75%;
    border: 3px dashed grey;
    padding: 4%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 12%;
    margin-bottom: 2%
  }
  #onthispage {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
  }
  #text1 {
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #text2 {
    width: 103%;
    height: 3%;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 549px) and (min-width: 404px) {
  #description1 {
    width: 80%;
    border: 3px dashed grey;
    padding: 4%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 2%
  }
  #onthispage {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
  }
  #text1 {
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #text2 {
    width: 103%;
    height: 3%;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 403px) {
  #description1 {
    width: 90%;
    border: 3px dashed grey;
    padding: 4%;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-bottom: 2%
  }
  #onthispage {
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
  }
  #text1 {
    margin-bottom: 4%;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #text2 {
    width: 103%;
    height: 3%;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}

.color {
  color: red;
}


/* Footer */

footer {
  background-color: #273037;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

footer p {
  padding: 10.5px;
  margin: 0px;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="keywords" content="learningenglish, learning english, " />
  <title>learningenglish.com</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepagefan.css" />
  <link href="img/learningenglish" rel="shortcuticon" type="image/x-icon" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
      <img src="img/english.png" width="80" height="40" alt="logo" title="Home">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportContent" aria-expend="false" aria-label="ToggleNavigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportContent">
      <ul class="topmenu">
        <li><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Present</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Present simple</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Present continuous</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Present perfect</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Past</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Past simple</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Past continuous</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Past perfect</a></li>
          </ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="submenu-link">Can, Will</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
              <li><a href="#">Can ,Could</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Will, Would</a></li>
            </ul>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container-fluid" id="carousel">
    <div id="carouselHome" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-target="carouselHome" data-slide-to="0"></li>
        <li class="active" data-target="carouselHome" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li class="active" data-target="carouselHome" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="img/city1.jpg" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="img/city2.jpg" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="img/city3.jpg" alt="" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#carouselHome" class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a href="#carouselHome" class="carousel-control-next" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="description1">
    <p id="onthispage">On this site you can find:</p>
    <p id="text1"><span class="color">Basic grammar English rules</span> (you can learn the rules that are easy to understand and to learn).</p>
    <p id="text2"><span class="color">Exercises in English</span> (you can do any exercises for Past, Present and Future).</p>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <p>Privacy policy © 2018 All rights reserved.</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `nav ul.topmenu {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать так (внесите правки в свой код):

**HTML**

```
<ul class="navbar-nav topmenu">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link submenu-link">Present</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Present simple</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Present continuous</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Present perfect</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link submenu-link">Past</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Past simple</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Past continuous</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Past perfect</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link submenu-link">Can, Will</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Can ,Could</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Will, Would</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.topmenu>li {
    /* width: 35%; */
    /* float: left; */
    position: relative;
}
```

Почему отказались от стандартного меню [navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#supported-content) который есть в **bootstrap v4.0**? Там же есть поддержка двухуровневого меню

**UPD**

*По поводу `.dropdown-item:hover`, `.dropdown-item:focus`*

Сначала подключаете файл стилей bootstrap, потом свои файлы стилей:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

В своем файле (в примере выше `style.css`) пишете, например:

```
.dropdown-item:hover, .dropdown-item:focus {
    background-color: red;
}
```

На тесте работает, при наведении или фокусе фон `.dropdown-item` будет красным. Рекомендую разобраться с [каскадированием стилей](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/kaskadirovanie).

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Может вы знаете у меня почему то не работает hover и focus. хотя я пробовал прописывать их  .dropdown-item:hover, .dropdown-item:focus {color: #FFD700;} и так .dropdown-item a:hover, .dropdown-item a:focus {color: #FFD700;} ,и .dropdown-item li a:hover, .dropdown-item li a:focus {color: #FFD700;}

Comment: Свой файл css нужно подключать после bootstrap. Посмотрите как определены стили .dropdown-item:hover и .dropdown-item:focus на элементах, и так же перепишите свойства в своем css

Comment: Не очень вас понимаю. Я смотрел сайт bootstrap и там написано что я должен написать -hover ,то есть .dropdown-item-hover. Я так сделал, но всё же не сработало.

Comment: обновил ответ. В документации не нашел упоминания о том, что нужно определить стили классов "dropdown-item-hover"